# SSIS Date/Numeric Conversion from Flatfile

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a Flat file which contains 2 columns . One is date time in this format

`2017-11-06T11:16:08 AM GMT`

and Another Column Total value stored in this format

`Â£39.00`.

Destination is OLEDB (ms sql),

```
Column 1 is Datetime and column 2 is Int in the destination
```

Data conversion in `SSIS` using Derived column is not returning required output for Column 1 (date)

PS: Destination data type can not be altered

[image]

[image: FlatFileSample Data]

Derived Column:

Column 2 is returning values with substring

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)SUBSTRING(Total,3,20)
```

Column 1 (orderDate) need to replace T and Am/Pm Values , output should be

```
2017-11-06 11:17:40   from 2017-11-06T11:16:08 AM GMT
```

[image]

Comment: Will column 2 always have data in whole pounds only?

Comment: Yes Always have data in those formats, but the destination does not have any symbols

Comment: You can do the data conversion in the `OLE DB Destination` with `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Comment: Ofcourse i knew, but destination structure can not be changed.

Comment: Post the code from the derived column and ole db destination in the question?

Comment: Personally I NEVER load directly to the production location. I always load to a staging table (in this case with varchar/nvarchar fields), do the clean up and then load to production. You will save yourself a lot of problems that way. If the conversion fails for instances, Then you have the data available to see what went wrong, rather than trying to see what is in a million record file.

Comment: I can set up alerts or notifications for failure for packages, i wouldn't even like to load this directly to the mapping tables, it will be straight froward if i use staging tables. Unfortunately requirement states the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression to achieve this:

```
SUBSTRING([Order date],1,10) + " " 
+ (FINDSTRING([Order date],"AM", 1 ) > 0 ? SUBSTRING([Order date],12,2)  : SUBSTRING([Order date],12,2)  == "12" ? "00" : (DT_WSTR, 2 )((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([Order date],12,2) + 12))
+ SUBSTRING([Order date],14,6)
```

Comment: Apologies for late reply, i think FINDSTRING works only with the DT_WSTR data type. It is DT_STR. I believe there must be a workaround with this

Comment: @BHouse `FINDSTRING` works for both string types (DT_STR & DT_WSTR), also you can simply cast the `Order Date` column using `(DT_WSTR,50)[Order date]`

Comment: Solved Thank you

Comment: @BHouse if this answer solved your question you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). just click on the mark under the voting arrows